# Broken count error : linux-generic-pae : Depends: linux-image-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.37.44) but 3.2.0.37.45 is installed

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

I am getting a broken count in synaptic and unable to fix it by running:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Following is the extract from the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic-pae : Depends: linux-image-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.37.44) but 3.2.0.37.45 is installed
                     Depends: linux-headers-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.37.44) but 3.2.0.37.45 is installed
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.distrib' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

The extract after running `sudo apt-get -f install` is below:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  openclient-about 3270-common ibm-config-anyconnect
  openclient-agnclient-notifications xfonts-x3270-misc libqt4-gui
  ibm-3270-emulator x3270 unity-lens-ocdc anyconnect ibm-cck-ff4
  ibm-lotus-upgrade-fix ibm-ocdc-documentation ocdc-unity-tweaks
  ibm-application-menus
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-generic-pae
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic-pae
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 181 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,728 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-image-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.37.44); however:
  Version of linux-image-generic-pae on system is 3.2.0.37.45.
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-headers-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.37.44); however:
  Version of linux-headers-generic-pae on system is 3.2.0.37.45.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.<br>
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-generic-pae
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.distrib' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am stuck and unable to do any further installs.

Answer (score 10):

I resolved a nearly identical problem (see below) by running `dpkg --remove linux-image-server` followed by `apt-get install linux-image-server`. Or in your case:

```
sudo dpkg --remove linux-generic-pae
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-pae
```

My problem was with the `linux-image-server` kernel metapackage rather than the `linux-generic-pae` metapackage, but the version numbers were the same:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-server : Depends: linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.37.44) but 3.2.0.37.45 is to be installed
                Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.37.44) but 3.2.0.37.45 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Had the same problem but with linux-generic package depending on a specific version of linux-image-generic and linux-headers-generic, but a newer version to be installed caused 'Unmet dependencies' error.
Solved it with `sudo dpkg --remove linux-generic && sudo apt-get install linux-generic`.
Thanks!

Comment: In my case the package was `linux-image-generic-pae` (note the difference between `linux-*` and `linux-image-*`—double-check the package names in the error message). Once I ran the two commands with the correct package names, everything was fine.