# "linux-image-generic" error while upgrading

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I encountered some problem while I was trying to upgrade my php5.3 to php5.4 or higher version.

Here's the command I typed `apt-get -f install php5.5`

And came out of this:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic : Depends: linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.116.132) but 3.2.0.124.139 is to be installed
                 Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 3.2.0.116.132) but 3.2.0.124.139 is to be installed
 php-amqp : Depends: php-common (>= 1:7.0+33~) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: phpapi-20160303 or
                     phpapi-20151012 or
                     phpapi-20131226 or
                     phpapi-20121212 but it is not installable
            Depends: librabbitmq4 (>= 0.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
 php-gearman : Depends: php-common (>= 1:7.0+33~) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: phpapi-20160303 or
                        phpapi-20151012 or
                        phpapi-20131226 or
                        phpapi-20121212 but it is not installable
               Depends: libgearman8 (>= 1.1.13) but it is not going to be installed
 php-geoip : Depends: php-common (>= 1:7.0+33~) but it is not going to be installed
```

The rest is pretty much the same labeled with `it is not going to be installed`

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

It looks like the `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` aren't matched to the one in need.

So the upgrade wasn't success and I was still stuck on php5.3.10.

I tried `dpkg --purge linux-image-generic` and `dpkg --purge linux-headers-generic` but still get the same error.

And `dpkg --configure -a` is also a no go.

Thoughts on this?

**UPDATE:**

After I followed Arijit's solution and typed `apt-get install php5`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic : Depends: linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.116.132) but 3.2.0.124.139 is to be installed
                 Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 3.2.0.116.132) but 3.2.0.124.139 is to be installed
 php5 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26 is to be installed or
                 libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-cgi (>= 5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-fpm (>= 5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: php5-common (>= 5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The version is still php5.3. And the `python properties` is the latest version.

This is the checks of the php5 versions. Tried `apt-get install php5.4.45`, couldn't be installed.

```
php5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1
  Version table:
     5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.3.10-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

**UPDATE2:**

After I dug a little more about the situation, I found solution here. [Broken count error : linux-generic-pae : Depends: linux-image-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.37.44) but 3.2.0.37.45 is installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251862/broken-count-error-linux-generic-pae-depends-linux-image-generic-pae-3-2?rq=1)

And the solution for my specific problem is the comment left by @Simon

> Had the same problem but with linux-generic package depending on a
>   specific version of linux-image-generic and linux-headers-generic, but
>   a newer version to be installed caused 'Unmet dependencies' error.
>   Solved it with `sudo dpkg --remove linux-generic && sudo apt-get
>   install linux-generic`. Thanks!

So the solution is pretty simple,

1. `sudo dpkg --remove linux-generic`
2. `sudo apt-get linux-generic`
3. Repeat the procedure of installing the php.

   - `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
   - `apt-get update`
   - `apt-get install php5.6` or `php7`
4. Noted that don't use Deprecated version of the PPA, please use `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` to get the latest version of safe and stable php.
5. `apt-get install php5.6` or `php7`.                 *php5.4 and lower are not supported anymore in 2015.*
6. There you have it, now you have successfully installed php5.6 and higher version. If not then restart your service. `sudo service apache2 restart` and `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: Post the solution in an answer instead of in the question, please

Comment: Like I answer to my own question?

Comment: yes, answering your own question is fine

Answer (score 0):

Please follow me here:

1. You have to update first and install Python Software Properties `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`
2. Now Add a PPA `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
3. Now update again `sudo apt-get update`
4. Check the available php5 version `apt-cache policy php5`
5. Now install php5.x `sudo apt-get install php5.4`
6. Check the php version now `php5 -v`, if not php5.4, then restart Apache `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` or `sudo service apache2 restart`

Hope it will be solved

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work Arijit, but still thank you. I updated my post, there's what happened after I follow the instruction.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that, will try to come up with a solution soon. Thanks

Comment: @EugeneRider: Just check with the PPA, seems the PPA name has changed. Updated my response with the new PPA. You may try it.

Comment: um... still didn't work. After step 5, there's `E: couldn't find pakage php5.4` error. If you type `php5`, it's the same problem with the linux generic.

Comment: Okay :(, anyway, will check further.

Comment: Hey man, problem solved.